# Private iOS Framework Returning NULL

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to use `BatteryCenter` and `CommonUtilities` private frameworks under iOS 9.1 with the help of [nst's iOS Runtime Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers). It's for research purposes and won't make it to the AppStore.

Here are their respective codes:

```
- (void)batteryCenter {
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework"];
BOOL success = [bundle load];

    if(success) {
        Class BCBatteryDevice = NSClassFromString(@"BCBatteryDevice");
        id si = [[BCBatteryDevice alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Charging: %@", [si valueForKey:@"charging"]);
    }
}


- (void)commonUtilities {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework"];
    BOOL success = [bundle load];

    if(success) {
        Class CommonUtilities = NSClassFromString(@"CUTWiFiManager");
        id si = [CommonUtilities valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];

        NSLog(@"Is Wi-Fi Enabled: %@", [si valueForKey:@"isWiFiEnabled"]);
        NSLog(@"Wi-Fi Scaled RSSI: %@", [si valueForKey:@"wiFiScaledRSSI"]);
        NSLog(@"Wi-Fi Scaled RSSI: %@", [si valueForKey:@"lastWiFiPowerInfo"]);
    }
}
```

Although I get the classes back, all of their respected values are NULL which is weird since some must be true, e.g. I'm connected to Wi-Fi so `isWiFiEnabled` should be `YES`.

What exactly is missing that my code doesn't return whats expected? Does it need entitlement(s)? If so what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, I managed to get this working without the `BatteryCenter` headers.  I'm still looking for a way to access the list of attached batteries without using `BCBatteryDeviceController`, but this is what I have working so far:

Swift 3:

```
guard case let batteryCenterHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework/BatteryCenter", RTLD_LAZY), batteryCenterHandle != nil else {
    fatalError("BatteryCenter not found")
}

guard let batteryDeviceControllerClass = NSClassFromString("BCBatteryDeviceController") as? NSObjectProtocol else {
    fatalError("BCBatteryDeviceController not found")
}

let instance = batteryDeviceControllerClass.perform(Selector(("sharedInstance"))).takeUnretainedValue()

if let devices = instance.value(forKey: "connectedDevices") as? [AnyObject] {

    // You will have more than one battery in connectedDevices if your device is using a Smart Case
    for battery in devices {
        print(battery)
    }
}
```

Swift 2.2:

```
guard case let batteryCenterHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework/BatteryCenter", RTLD_LAZY) where batteryCenterHandle != nil else {
    fatalError("BatteryCenter not found")
}

guard let c = NSClassFromString("BCBatteryDeviceController") as? NSObjectProtocol else {
    fatalError("BCBatteryDeviceController not found")
}

let instance = c.performSelector("sharedInstance").takeUnretainedValue()
if let devices = instance.valueForKey("connectedDevices") as? [AnyObject] {

    // You will have more than one battery in connectedDevices if your device is using a Smart Case
    for battery in devices {
        print(battery)
    }
}
```

This logs:

```
<BCBatteryDevice: 0x15764a3d0; vendor = Apple; productIdentifier = 0; parts = (null); matchIdentifier = (null); baseIdentifier = InternalBattery-0; name = iPhone; percentCharge = 63; lowBattery = NO; connected = YES; charging = YES; internal = YES; powerSource = YES; poweredSoureState = AC Power; transportType = 1 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first access the `BCBatteryDeviceController`, after success block is executed, through which you can get list of all the connected devices.

Here is the code for the same.

```
Class CommonUtilities = NSClassFromString(@"BCBatteryDeviceController");

id si = [CommonUtilities valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];

BCBatteryDeviceController* objBCBatteryDeviceController = si;

NSLog(@"Connected devices: %@", objBCBatteryDeviceController.connectedDevices);
```